# Type Hierarchy precondition and postcondition, how to know if subclass has "stronger" or "weaker "precondition and postcondition than superclass?

Tags: java, oop, hierarchy

This is the specific slide that contains the information I need answers for precondition and postcondition.

[image: Type hierarchy methods rule]

Comment: The slide you have shown us gives the answer.  Precisely.  In mathematical notation.  What is your actual question?

Comment: @StephenC Like I asked in the title, I don't understand how the precondition in the superclass is "stronger" than that in the subclass and the same with the postcondition

Comment: You know that it is "weaker" or "stronger" by proving that the predicate "pre<sub>super</sub> => pre<sub>sub</sub>" is true ... etcetera.  The "=>" means "implies".